# R - time series, plotting crime data by Year and Number of crimes where crimes is at=10^(0:6)

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

I have a data frame with variables:

```
$ ID                  : int  9224101
$ IUCR                : Factor w/ 360
$ Primary.Type        : Factor w/ 32
$ Year                : int  2013
```

IUCR (Illinois Uniform Crime Reporting code)

I want to plot a time series that shows all the Years on x axis and the number of crimes that happened each year on Y axis at=10^(0:6) , so the numbers wouldnt be as high.

I've tried using:

```
plot.ts(dd$Year, dd$ID)
```

[image]

Ive also tried

```
ggplot(data = dd, aes(Year, ID)) +geom_line()
```

Comment: What is the question? Please explain what you are looking for.

Comment: I doubt the ID variable is the one you want to plot.  Is there another field that actually lists the number of crimes?  I don't see it in your variable list.

Comment: There is no variable that specifically counts the number of crimes -  I assumed R was able to do it for me by looking at Year and counting how many ID match that year. It's my first time using R. Should I in that case count the total for each year and put the values in 2 new variables and use those to plot ?

Comment: > aggregate(cbind(Year) ~ Year, data = dd, sum)

       Year     Year
    1  2001 77814888

    2  2002 78546468

    3  2003 76440489

    4  2004 76330356

    5  2005 73342900
    6  2006 73180886  
    7  2007 71164206
    8  2008 70514936 
    9  2009 64517026
    10 2010 60402510
    11 2011 57595040 
    12 2012 54605680
    13 2013 50091492
    14 2014 44728926
    15 2015 42345225
    16 2016 32128992

I think this is the number of crimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each observation represents one crime then you could do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
dd$count <- 1
dd_by_year <- dd %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize(crime = sum(count, na.rm = T))
```

Then you should have crime by year that you can plot in any manner you like.

Comment: In that case how do I plot that so it gets the sum for each year. Sorry It's my first time using R.

Comment: `plot(crime~Year,data=dd_by_year)`

Comment: Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: I tried it again after installing the correct library and it worked, Thank you